# No extra line-height on item that's too long to fit on one row?

Tags: html, css

I have a standard list like

```
<ul>
<li>short item</li>
<li>looooooooooooooong iiiiiiiiiiitem</li>
<li>short item</li>
<ul>
```

The list have a max width and therefore the long item covers two rows and get the same line-height as the other items so it looks like four items if you just have a glance at it.

Is there a way to let the long item take up two "rows" but with less line-height between them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to compare the line-height to the offset height of the string. If the height of the text is larger than the line-height, you know it takes up more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use css `:first-line` property for this:

```
li:first-line{
    line-height:30px;
}
li{
    line-height:10px;
    font-size:14px;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;   
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/EN4SX/